# Open ASF with J2ME

Tags: java-me, asf

I'm on a project right now and I'd like to know how to play an ASF file on a cellphone. What do I need to do to get it done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is supported on phones, usually, mp3, aac, etc are suported. However if you can convert from ASF to say mp3, then almost all phones support that format.